# Hadoop MapReduce Job stuck because auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've checked multiple posts with the same questions, and the solution is always adding the following to the yarn-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarm.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I covered both properties in the config and restarted yarn. The problem still remains.

The error is:

```
17/02/15 15:43:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1487202110321_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1487202110321_0001_01_000007 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I was hoping for a typo but can't seem to find it. Tried directly copy what's on stackoverflow into the xml file, still doesn't work.

What else can I try?

EDIT:

Since the error says the aux_service should be `auxService`, i modified the yarn-site.xml according, changing all `aux-service` to `auxService`, but it's still not working.

EDIT2:

In case anyone's interested, I call this command

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.jar \
       -input /user/myfolder/input1/* \
       -output /user/myfolder/output1 \
       -mapper <path>/<to>/<mapper>/mapper.py \
       -reducer <path>/<to>/<reducer>/reducer.py
```

while I'm already in `/usr/local/cellar/hadoop/2.7.1/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/`

EDIT 3:

I'm a dumbass. proof-read the script guys!

Comment: Have you deployed the modified yarn-site.xml to all nodes?

Comment: I'm running on single node

Comment: Not sure this is an issue, it must be `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services` not `yarm.nodemanager.aux-services`.

Comment: this.....is embarrassing..... that's the issue.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the property name in `yarn-site.xml` as `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services`,

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```