# Hive on AWS EMR - error when sending 'count (*)'

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hive, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I have EMR and Hive in it.

If I open Hive console and run: `select * from table` - works fine.
Also if I run `select * from table where ID > 2` (or any filter) - it works fine.

But when I run: `select count(*) from table` - it shows error:

```
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Container launch failed for container_1597771662497_0002_01_000006 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateExceptionImpl(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Have tou tried updating yarn-site.xml as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262335/hadoop-mapreduce-job-stuck-because-auxservicemapreduce-shuffle-does-not-exist ?

Comment: Yes, that was the thing.. no idea why EMR does not come with that automatically?!  Also Yarn needs to be restarted (which noone mention)..

Comment: ...and the reason your first two queries work is because they are executed in map-local mode on the client without launching any MR jobs.

Comment: @mazaneicha why would EMR not have TEZ or also not have hive server up and running by default?

Comment: SO is not the right place to ask this. And... what do you need tez for anyway?

Comment: Why not for both?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What is the answer :)

Comment: Use beeline instead of Hive.